# How to prove: The stereographic projection is orientation reversing (Complex Analysis by Theodore W. Gamelin 1.3.3)?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, rotations, riemann-sphere

This problem is in my book:

> Show that as $z$ traverses a small circle in the complex plane in the
> positive (counterclockwise) direction, the corresponding point $P$ on
> the sphere traverses a small circle in the negative (clockwise) direction with respect to someone standing at the center of the circle and with body outside the sphere ( the stereographic projection
> is orientation reversing, as a map from the sphere with orientation
> determined by the unit outer normal vector to the complex plane
> with the usual orientation.)).

[image]

I face some problems trying to solve this exercise:
The first problem is I barely remember anything from analytic geometry so I tried to do thing on my own. Second problem: How to define and express rotation mathematically? It is easy in complex plane i.e $a+bi + re^{i \theta} $ detriment a rotation for a point moving  in complex plane with center at $a+bi$ and radius $r$ if $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi - \varepsilon 
$ this rotation is positive otherwise the rotation is negative, But how to define and express the rotation in the circle on the sphere i.e n 3D? After some thought all the ideas that I came with  seems to be complicated and require a lot of calculations (I think this question is simple but I just forgot analytic geometry) one idea is to make a projection of the  circle on the sphere and this shape will be an ellipse, now I need to define what does it mean for a direction of rotation on ellipse mathematically and use that to express rotation but this seem to be very complected to say the least. The third problem is How do I prove this statement?.

Pretty sure I am overthinking this problem and it has a very simple and short proof without all my complicated and dumb methods.

---

[image]

It is easy to see that this statement is true after visualising  the problem and following the points with  your finger, but how to write a **Rigorous** mathematical proof?

Comment: (1) the 1st picture doesn't match the text block-- it both overloads $z$ and shows a negatively oriented curve in the complex plane. (2) I don't know your book that well and whether or not it adequately defines winding numbers, orientation, etc. *That said:* I strongly suggest you focus on the simplest case to get more or less all of the results: focus on a positively oriented curve around the unit circle-- the stereographic projection sends the unit circle to the equator in a particularly simple manner, but instead of standing on the north pole they want you to stand on the south pole so...

Comment: @user8675309 Can you write an answer? or  give me any link thank has a proof?